# sql join if value exists in other table then Count it

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following tables.

Table A

```
 UserID | key
 1      | A
 2      | B
 3      | A
 4      | C
 5      |
```

Table B

```
UserID | Num
1      | 50
1      | 300
2      |
3      | 100
4      | 20
```

I have query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(key) AS cnt, key 
FROM A 
WHERE key <> '' 
GROUP BY key 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The results should be something like this

```
 key | cnt
 A   | 2
 B   | 1
 C   | 1
```

What I would like to add is Joining Table B. 
If UserID  has value in Num in Table B, I would like to count UserID with/Num Grouped by key

Here is desired results

```
 key | cnt | Has Num?
 A   | 2   | 2
 B   | 1   | 0
 C   | 1   | 1
```

I tried to write subquery but I can't attach it to main query. Subquery is something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS num 
FROM B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON B.UserID = A.UserID 
WHERE Num <>'' AND key <> '' 
GROUP BY key
```

Comment: How come [Has Num?] for A is 2...it must be 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, what you're looking for is a count of the Keys in Table A when they were used by a UserID, and then a count of the number of unique UserIDs in Table B who both appeared in the first Table A query and had a Num.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.[Key], COUNT(a.[Key]) AS cnt, isNull(SUM(b.bCnt), 0) AS [Has Num?]
FROM #TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT b.UserID, 1
    FROM #TableB b
    WHERE LEN(b.Num) > 0
    GROUP BY b.UserID
) b (UserID, bCnt) ON b.UserID = a.UserID
WHERE LEN(a.[Key]) > 0 
GROUP BY a.[Key]
```

This query gives the results that you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE(UserID INT, [Key] CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'A'),(4,'C'),(5,'')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE(UserID INT, Num INT NULL)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES(1,50),(1,300),(2,NULL),(3,100),(4,20)


SELECT x.[Key],x.Cnt,y.[Has Num?]
FROM 
    (   SELECT [Key],Cnt = COUNT([Key])
        FROM @TableA 
        WHERE LEN([Key])>0
        GROUP BY [Key]
    )X
JOIN
    (
        SELECT a.[Key],[Has Num?] = COUNT(b.Num)
        FROM @TableA a
        JOIN @TableB b ON a.UserID = b.UserID
        GROUP BY a.[Key]
    )Y
ON x.[Key] = Y.[Key]


Key Cnt Has Num?
A   2   3
B   1   0
C   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT [Key], COUNT(a.[Key]) AS cnt, SUM(x.NumCount) AS [Has Num?]    
FROM @TableA a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(NUM) AS NumCount 
             FROM  @TableB b 
             WHERE b.UserId = a.UserId AND Num IS NOT NULL
            ) x
WHERE [Key] <> '' 
GROUP BY [Key]
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Result:

```
Key  cnt         Has Num?
---- ----------- -----------
A    2           3
B    1           0
C    1           1
```